# How to remove link tab in images for CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I am able to remove other tabs like Advanced in images and and another tab in links but, I the same method is not working for link tab.

I edited config.js file like this and it worked for advanced tab:
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';

But when I edited config.js file for link tab then it didn't work:
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';'image:link';!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QNy0.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at [`config.removeDialogTabs` docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeDialogTabs). This config is case sensitive as described there, so the proper form should be:

`config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;image:Link';`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, the Advanced tab actually hiding with "advanced" so I thought to write "Link" in the same way but, never thought that it might be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using ckeditor.js file you can change the distribution version below is the example

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/[version.number]/[distribution]/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

**The following distributions (see comparison table) are available:**

- **basic** - the Basic preset
  **standard** - the Standard preset
  **standard-all** - the Standard preset together with all other plugins created by CKSource*
  **full** - the Full preset
  **full-all** - the Full preset together with all other plugins created by CKSource*
  Link copied from

  https://cdn.ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you have a config file for ckeditor:

```
   CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
        dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;


    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
}
};
```